# Find out who adds a specific auto layout constraint

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

How do I find out who adds a specific auto layout constraint?

Because I'm seeing some constraints which I'm certain I did not add.

Comment: Did you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`?

Comment: Start using storyboards and xibs to define constraints. You will see that many such problems will go away. A constraint can be created from autoresizing mask for example. Sometimes a constraint can be added automatically when the current constraint are not suficient.

Comment: @BallpointBen, Yes.

Comment: @matt, It's a generic question.

Comment: @matt, "And the generic answer" is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42807700/865175). Now please remove your downvote.

Comment: I'm not interested in your book. 1. A symbolic breakpoint would stop at __exactly__ where it was created so you'll see "who added it". 2. If you set the `accessibilityIdentifier` for your `UIView`s, you could distinguish them from others so you'll yet again know "who added" the constraints. You can also edit questions. Now please remove your downvote.

Comment: @matt, Am I right or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** the layout is *ambiguous* or *unsatisfiable*, you can put a symbolic breakpoint on `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints`.

You can add a `Debugger Command` containing `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]` for Objective-C or `expr -l objc++ -O -- [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]` for Swift which automatically prints the `UIView` hierarchy, as desribed in [this article](http://nshint.io/blog/2015/08/17/autolayout-breakpoints).
You can also use `po $r15` in the debugger to print the "details description of constraint that is broken" or `po $r14` for "more detailed description of all constraints added in addition to breaking constraint", as described in [this article](http://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/debugging-breaking-constraints-in-the-xcode).

If not, you can set the [`accessibilityIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiaccessibilityidentification/1623132-accessibilityidentifier) for your `UIView` *(or [directly in the IB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33751458/865175))* which will show up in the previous expressions' results (and other places too) instead of the string `UIView`.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift you could look at `var identifier: String?`. If it starts with `NS` then it was added by iOS.

```
A constraint’s identifier is available in its description. Identifiers that start with NS are reserved by the system.
```

Comment: And if doesn't?

Comment: If the identifier is blank it's likely a constraint you added via code, a storyboard, or XIB